# How to write ini_set in php

Tags: php

How to increase file uploading size by ini_set in php. The defult file size is 2mb. but i want to increase the size.

```
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$location="news/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];


$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news(image) VALUES('$location')");

if(!$q)
{
echo mysql_error();
}
else
{

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../news/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$_SESSION['mass_added']= 'echo"you are logged in"';
echo "<script>window.location = 'manage_news.php?user_type=admin'</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it with `ini_set()`. Check:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

**PHP_INI_PERDIR**

`Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)`

Comment: Just a question, could you lower those limits? (increasing I know you cannot)

Comment: @Lexib0y No, the setting can not be changed with `ini_set()`.

Comment: Scottish: Ye cannae dae it wi' `ini_set()`!